# Shell script with user input prompt

Tags: bash, scripts

Is it possible to write a script where the initial command requires user input so that it prompts the user to enter that input before running?

Example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:"this"/"and_that"
```

Comment: Use [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/742950/216503)..no need for using `echo` ....`read` has `-p` option to prompt to user..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read user input in bash the following way:

```
read -p "Input this: " this
read -p "Input that: " that
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:${this}/${that}
```

[`read`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) command creates a variable with its value taken from standard input.

In real life scenario you should also sanitize user input (i.e. check for non-alphanumeric characters before calling the command), but you can skip it if it's just for you.

Comment: The reference for read says: "The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a terminal." I don't know what exactly that means. Is there some situation where prompt is not shown?

Comment: For example if you pipe the input values to the script `printf "this\nthat" | bash yourscript.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You can use command `read` to read user input into variables.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter this:
read this

echo and that:
read and_that

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:$this/$and_that
```

Comment: Why `echo` -ing?